# VB 2008 Express program cancel close

Tags: vb.net, terminate

I need help with Visual Basic 2008 Express Programs. What I did is when we click the **CAPTION BAR (of Windows on top-right) CLOSE BUTTON** I have set it to prompt Yes/No/Cancel Box, the code follows:

```
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Dim closePrompt = MessageBox.Show("Save changes to your file (if any)?", "Text Editor", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3)
        If closePrompt = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            SaveFileDialog1.FileName = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        ElseIf closePrompt = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf closePrompt = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        'Here I need help to cancel the close command'
        End If
    End Sub
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```